# How to find the number of non null properties in an object

Tags: java

I have an object `Card` and has properties/fields `name`, `id`, `date`, `number`. How to find the number of non null fields. That is the number of fields that have been set. I do not have the list of functions or don't want to go down that road.

Eg:

```
  card.setName("abc");
```

I want the count to be 1 because only name is set.

Comment: Why count non-null fields? What if only `date` is set? Then count is 1, but `name` is still not set. You should check all properties individually or use proper means to make sure that whatever limitations you have, they hold (e.g. appropriate constructors).

Comment: I just gave it as an example. Count can be 4 also with all the fields set.

Answer (score -1):

Check the fields and increment counter if the field is not null:

```
public int countNotNullFields(Card card) {
    int counter = 0;
    if (card.getName() != null) {
        counter++;
    }
    ...
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Reflection is the only sane approach here.

Comment: Sane?!...
The op says he has an **object** with a defined count of fields. So for the described use case my code would work as requested. 
For sure, a more generic approach would be reflection, but that depends on the use case the op wants to implement. So why that downvote for correct code?

Comment: I don't have the function list with me. So the previous solution wont work. Also I would need a more generic case. Its not just the name field that might be set.